# Чи існує український аналог клавіатури (розкладки) Дворака?

Tags: software

Говорять, що англійська розкладка QWERTY була [спроектована навмисне неефективною](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sholes_and_Glidden_typewriter#QWERTY_keyboard), аби уникати збивання механічних важелів докупи під час швидкого друкування. Згодом було розроблено безліч альтернативних розкладок, що покращують швидкість набору, найбільш відомою з яких є [клавіатура Дворака](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0_%D0%94%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B0).

На сьогодні в українській мові використовується розкладка ЙЦУКЕН, яка є копією російської ЙЦУКЕН, що в свою чергою також [не вважається ідеальною для швидкого друку](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D1%8B#.D0.A0.D1.83.D1.81.D1.81.D0.BA.D0.B8.D0.B5_.D1.80.D0.B0.D1.81.D0.BA.D0.BB.D0.B0.D0.B4.D0.BA.D0.B8_.D0.BA.D0.BB.D0.B0.D0.B2.D0.B8.D0.B0.D1.82.D1.83.D1.80.D1.8B).

Чи існують альтернативні розкладки, в яких розташування клавіш підібрано з врахуванням частоти вживань літер і літеросполучень в **українських** словах?

Answer (score 4):

Аналіз тематичних інтернет-ресурсів дає вкрай мало інформації про такі розкладки.

Є [фонетичні розкладки](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%B0), є такі, що [сформовані на основі розкладок друкарських машинок](https://www.terena.org/activities/multiling/koi8-u/DSTU_3470.html). Але інформація про розкладки, що базуються на принципі частоти і ергономіки, у відкритих джерелах практично відсутня.

[Єдина згадка](http://web.archive.org/web/20160401093256/http://layout.asharapov.com/about/), яку мені вдалось відкопати про таку розкладку, наводиться у коментарі до питання. Вона виглядає наступним чином:

[image: Ukrainian dessktop "Sharapivka" layout]

Однак, єдиний сайт, присвячений цій розкладці канув у лету.

Беручи до уваги те, що якщо б існувала така розкладка, то інформація з *великою ймвірністю* була б у інтернеті (а вона відсутня), то, вважаю, можна стверджувати, що **актуальних розкладок**, про які мова іде у питанні, немає.

Comment: Власне, мені знається, основне питання по суті навіть не в розкладці — створити свою розкладку кожен дурень може. А скоріше в тому: (1) чи були якісь дослідження; (2) чи набула якась нестандартна розкладка популярності (навіть не на основі досліджень). Але, так, окрім «самопальної» від О. Шарапова (фонетичні я не рахую, бо вони не зовсім українські (лише розташовують українські літери аналогічно до іншомовної), а «друкарські» — теж ЙЦУКЕН) — здається, нічого.

Comment: Хоча оту «шарапівку» — хоч в неї напевне вкладено значно менше досліджень, ніж у Дворака — мабуть, можна вважати спробою зробити саме аналог розкладки Дворака. Бо метою «шарапівки» було «розташування клавіш найуживаніших літер у центрі та середньому ряді клавіатури. Таким чином, під час друку пальці здійснюють менше рухів, ніж на стандартній розкладці. Менше рухів — більше швидкість». А розташування науживаніших літер на home row було й однією (хоч не єдиною) з цілей розкладки Дворака.